# Bash parameter substitution

Tags: bash, parameters, substitution

I am trying to learn bash parameter substitution and have a very basic question:

Why does this work:

```
#!/bin/sh
v1="-E"
v2="s/./x/g"
sed "$v1" "$v2" <<<"abc" # result = "xxx"
```

but this doesn't work:

```
#!/bin/sh
v1="-E"
v2="s/./x/g"
sed "$v1 $v2" <<<"abc" # result = "sed: illegal option..."
```

I am using Mac OS X bash.

Comment: You should enquote the regex like this `sed "$v1 '$v2'" <<<"abc"`

Comment: I tried that and it gives the same error message.

Comment: @scolfax You should learn about wordsplitting: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting

Comment: Word splitting, multiple types of expansion, command substation...lots of good stuff to learn. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because on the second example, (the wrong one) you are using the quotes wrong. The quotes are being used in order to specify that what whatever comes out of that variable has to be treated as a string, and you added two variables in one of them. each one has to be seperated, because like this its like saying its one variable, so sed sees one variable not two. So for example, lets say:

```
v1=123
v2=456
```

as you have it on the second example, sed will see this: "123456", though what you want sed to see is two variables, one to have 123 and the second one to have 456. Thats why you should have them in seperated quotes!
I hope i explained it good enough for you to understand!!

**P.S**

What you actually did on the second example, you could use it at some point if you want to concutenate two variables, and add them in another as a string :)

**UPDATE**

So lets have an example here.....

```
v1=123
v2=456
CASE1="$v1" "$v2"
CASE2="$v1 $v2"
echo CASE1
echo CASE2
```

For the CASE1 the output would be 123456, as for the CASE2 the output would be 123 456..... Do you get the difference now?
The only way to do it in both ways and print out the same thing would be this.....

```
v1=123
v2=456
CASE1="$v1" "$v2"
CASE2="$v1$v2"
```

having the case2 WITHOUT a space between the variables...

Comment: I don't think I grasp it yet. In the second example, there is a space between $v1 and $v2. Wouldn't that result in the string "-E s/./x/g" after substitution and thus be equivalent to the first example?

Comment: @scolfax let me give you a simple example..... is it the same if i give you one punch on the face or if i give you two? :p just kidding btw, i just made a funny point :)

Comment: @scolfax my point was that, it is not the same thing if you pass two variables  or one on sed, lets take an example to see it better.... check the update on the answer.

Comment: I think I know where my thinking was wrong. The key is that the quotes change the meaning of the space character. Without quotes, the space character is treated as a command parameter separator, but with the quotes, the space character is treated as a character in a character string. Is that correct?

Comment: @scolfax You got it!!! I never like to give ready made answers, like for example Michael did, because you dont actually learn that way, this way i gave you food for thought and you got it on your own :) so next time easier troubleshooting for you :D

Comment: Indeed, the pain on my face will forever ingrain this lesson on bash parameter substitution into my psyche!

Comment: @scolfax hehehehe, anyways, good that i managed to help you out, if you dont have something else to ask, please choose the answer that you think it helped you more so this post can be closed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your second example is that double quotes protect enclosed whitespace from word splitting in Bash:

Instead of two arguments `-E` and `s/./x/g`, only one single argument `-E s/./x/g` (containing a blank) will be passed to the respective `exec()` system call and finally to `sed` in that case.

Comment: That explains it! Thank you very much.