# How to not interpret $ into bash script

Tags: mongodb, bash, docker, hash, special-characters

i made a bin/bash command file that tried to 
executes differents commands into a docker container.

When i launch the following command:

```
password='$2y$10$vXBqzZa3oNhMG/3qj10weehWDP4rkfn/R0sctThBb5nLDpLjOlLSu'

docker exec -it ${imageName} /bin/sh -c "mongo -u user -p password --eval \"db = db.getSiblingDB('db'); db.users.insertOne({'role':'Admin', 'name':'aaa', 'email':'a@a.com', 'password': '${password}' }); db.users.find();\" "
```

it run and successfully insert the new 'Admin' user into database 'db' (mongoDb) 
but it wrongly parse the 'password' variable.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d7d4aee81d1b750455423ef"), "role" : "Admin", "name" : "aaa", "email" : "a@a.com", "password" : "y0/3qj10weehWDP4rkfn/R0sctThBb5nLDpLjOlLSu" }
```

I think the bash interprets the special character $ as a variable.

So the first part of password:
$2y$10$vXBqzZa3oNhMG

became:
y0

Thanks in advice for the help.

Comment: use a single quote rather than a double quote

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash parameter substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36938295/bash-parameter-substitution)

Comment: Generally you shouldn't be using `docker exec` for interacting with the network services your container provides.  Install the `mongo` client on your host system and call your service normally.  (If you were running this on a real server, would you ssh as root into the server to insert data?)

Comment: If you do insist on this approach, the `/bin/sh -c` wrapper isn't necessary, and the additional layer of quoting will cause trouble.  Try adding `echo` to the very front of the command just to see what the shell is doing with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The single quotes around Password did the job to prevent shell expansion but what about the mongo shell as again you are using `--eval \"db` double quotes which will expend the shell variable? So you still need to escape the shell expansion in mongo shell in the password variable, so better to add escape character in the password.

```
password='\$2y\$10\$vXBqzZa3oNhMG/3qj10weehWDP4rkfn/R0sctThBb5nLDpLjOlLSu'
echo ${password}
docker exec -it ${imageName}  \
/bin/sh -c "mongo -u root -p root_password --eval \"db = db.getSiblingDB('db'); db.users.insertOne({'role':'Admin', 'name':'aaa', 'email':'a@a.com', 'password': '${password}' }); db.users.find();\""
```